# GUI to set numeric ranges in Delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface, range

Once in a while I need a GUI to set **numeric ranges**, but so far I've never really found any component that does it nicely.

I've attempted the following:

- 2 TTrackbars: 1 for min, 1 for max
- 2 TTackbars: 1 for min, 1 for range
- 2 TSpinEdit controls to type the numbers manually
- [image: ttrackbar with range] 
  1 TTrackbar control, with a little button to switch between min-mode and max-mode. In min-mode I set selStart and in max-mode I set selEnd (with ShowSelRange set to true).

Most options take more screen estate than I'd like, and they are not intuitive.

Ideally, I'd like something that works like the scrollbar in Sony ACID. You can click and drag 3 different points to the min, max, or both:

[image: Awesome mspaint drawing]

Is there any Free component available to set a range, or can something similar be done by using out-of-the-box VCL components creatively?

---

## Update

I've modified TMkRangeSlider to suit my needs. It works like a charm now. I've sent the modified component and demo to the original author.

[image: TMkRangeSlider 1.1]

Comment: could you please share the modified code?

Comment: @reron: ok, it's been a decade, but here's the file that I've used back then. Set `ShowMidBar` to true, and `ThumbStyle` to `rsRectangle` to make it look like the screenshot above. https://gist.github.com/WouterVanNifterick/19bfec13a4935187ca6838e38de92a94

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like [Range Slider, by Michael Kochiashvili](http://www.kochini.com/dcomp/rs/). It is freeware with source, written for Delphi 5 and comes with a demo:

[image]

It won't move min and max simultaneously, but since you've got the source, you could probably add that functionality if you really need it.

Comment: Cool, never saw that one before. Just downloaded it, and i'll be playing around with it.

Comment: I've taken your advice by taking TMkRangeSlider and modifying it. It does exactly what I was looking for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Wouter van Nifterick, please share the modified code

Comment: @Reron: https://gist.github.com/WouterVanNifterick/19bfec13a4935187ca6838e38de92a94

Comment: Any chance anyone has converted this to FMX?

Answer (score 1):

Using a standard TScrollBox, it is technically possible to do some manual fiddling of its PageSize and Position properties while dragging its thumb around (ScrollCode=scTrack in its OnScroll event) to simulate the kind of UI that you showed in the ACID screenshot.  The problem is that 1) you can't owner-draw a TScrollBar to add the drag lines, and 2) there is no direct way to determine which portion of the thumb the user is holding the mouse down on (the ends versus the middle).  Unless you can come up with some fairly reliable calculations to figure out the pixel offsets of the left and right edges of the thumb based on the current Position and PageSize in relation to the overall client rectangle, then you are probably best off simply writing your own component instead, and then you can make it look and behave anyway you want.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice. It's strange that Delphi doesn't have anything like this, because setting numeric ranges is something I need to do all the time, in all sorts of applications...

Comment: The kind of UI you are describing is not standard.  That is why TScrollBox does not support it natively (because the underlying OS itself does not support it natively)